# does constexpr impact performance of static code analysis?

Tags: c++, constexpr

How does `constexpr` affect static code analysis performance of C++ in IDEs(e.g. Visual Studio)? Are there any situations where using them can greatly impact static code analysis performance?

Comment: I would say it should depend of analyser, if they have code specific for constexpr/non-constexpr functions.

Comment: I think this question is far too broad. Any tool can be designed _badly_, which would affect performance of the analysis. Valid constexpr code is otherwise valid C++ code, so there in theory should not really be a huge impact, other than a minor additional check on the evaluated constant. A question like this really needs to be asked about a specific tool or tools IMO